# Link to Manage Subscription in iOS App ends up a blank screen

Tags: ios, swift, itunes, in-app-subscription

I am trying to open this link [itmss://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions](http://itmss://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscription) for managing subscription in my iPhone but it ends up in a blank screen and doesn't show anything. Have anyone else facing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling a bit, I found this link working

[itms-apps://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions](http://itms-apps://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions)

Comment: You got this to work from within an iOS app? My app crashes with error: "The specified URL has an unsupported scheme. Only HTTP and HTTPS URLs are supported."

Comment: Yeah, it still working in my app. Make sure that you are testing in device not in simulator